# How do I build a complex nested form to represent dynamic attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I've got a data model represented by the following image:
[image]

Basically, the idea is that there are many different **Collections**.   All the **Items** in a single collection will have the same **Attributes**, but the list of attributes will be different per collection.    The value of each Attribute per item will be stored in **Item Attribute Values**.

I'm trying to build a single page where a user can populate the attributes for an item. I'm assuming a nested form is the way to go but I'm at a loss as to how to represent this in the controller and on the page, considering the names of the attributes are in one table and the values in another.

If anyone has encountered or had to deal with a similar situation, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Will a given type of item only appear in one collection? E.g., all items with the attributes "name", "age", "height" will be in a single "Persons" collection? Or could you find a "person" in more than one collection?

Comment: Could be in more than one collection.    Collections are independent of one another and are tied to users, so two different users may end up creating identical collections.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one potential solution.

```
class Collection
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
  has_and_belongs_to_many :attributes
end

class Item
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collections
  has_many :item_attributes
  has_many :attributes, though: :item_attributes
end

class Attributes
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collections
  has_many :item_attributes
  has_many :items, though: :item_attributes
end

class ItemAttribute
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :attribute
end
```

So lets look at the database layout to back these models:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151027173337) do

  create_table "attributes_collections", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "attribute_id",  null: false
    t.integer "collection_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "collections", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "collections", ["user_id"], name: "index_collections_on_user_id"

  create_table "collections_items", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "collection_id", null: false
    t.integer "item_id",       null: false
  end

  create_table "item_attributes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "attribute_id"
    t.string   "value"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  add_index "item_attributes", ["attribute_id"], name: "index_item_attributes_on_attribute_id"
  add_index "item_attributes", ["item_id"], name: "index_item_attributes_on_item_id"

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

### A Better way?

But of course performance will suffer due to the many joins. Plus each attribute will be stored as a VARCHAR which means you can't do any numeric comparisons in the database.

If you really need a flexible schema i would instead look into using [HSTORE, JSON](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/07/03/hstore-vs-json/) or another dynamic column type or a schemaless database such as MongoDB.

### How do I create a form / controller for this?

First you should get very acquainted with what can be done with [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) and maybe consider using AJAX to delegate the actions out to `CollectionController` and a `ItemController` on the back end rather than cramming it all into a single monstrosity.

Comment: Thanks.   I've got the models defined similarly to what you've got there, although I've defined some of the has_many_and_belongs_to relationships simply as has_many, or belong_tos.   For example, a collection has_many items, and does not belong_to any items.   I guess the one thing I'm missing is the relationship between Item and Attributes, which I thought unnecessary because I'm establishing that relationship through the Collection.    However, putting that in there will allow me to use the :through aspect of the has_many.

Comment: I'm still having issues with this.   Would you be able to comment on what the controller and view would look like to get this working?   On the view, I'd like to have a list of text fields representing the different attributes (coming from ItemAttributes) along with a label (which comes from Attributes).    I'm assuming this needs to be a fields_for scenario, because since I'm also collecting base item info (not attributes) on this form.